# items of listwidgets in pyqt4 doesn't work properly

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4

```
    self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.search)

def search(self):
    import subprocess
    keyword = str(unicode(self.lineEdit.text()))
    subprocess.call(["some command"])
    video_list = []
    self.listWidget.clear()
    video_ret = parse_vid(video_list)
    self.listWidget.addItems(video_ret)
    self.listWidget.itemDoubleClicked.connect(self.surf)

#######################################################################
def surf(self):
    print "hello"
```

This code work fine for first time. But if I click pushbutton for the second time item click in listwidget gives me two execution of surf method. If I click pushbutton third time item click in listwidget execute surf method three time. Can any one help me with this weird problem??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A signal can be connected to multiple slots, in your case whenever you use the search function you are adding a new slot, it is better to add it once.

```
    self.listWidget.itemDoubleClicked.connect(self.surf)
    self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.search)

def search(self):
    import subprocess
    keyword = str(unicode(self.lineEdit.text()))
    subprocess.call(["some command"])
    video_list = []
    self.listWidget.clear()
    video_ret = parse_vid(video_list)
    self.listWidget.addItems(video_ret)

#######################################################################
def surf(self):
    print("hello")
```